# XDebug halts execution on caught-exceptions

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I'm using VSCode + PHP Debug extension, and when I debug my application, the script execution is halted on any exception, even if it has been caught.

[image]

Extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

XDebug settings

```
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.show_exception_trace=0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had the same issue Xdebug being stopped at pretty much everything it goes through.

If you go to the `Debug` panel of VS Code and at the bottom check for the `Breakpoints` section. Disable Notices, Exceptions, Everything and Warnings (or whatever suits you best).

I basically keep the aforementioned 4 settings unticked so that it will only stop at my breakpoints.

Screenshot of the settings: [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QZQq.jpg) (Unfortunately, SO's image uploading plugin doesn't seem to work for me!)

Hope this helps :)